# Unable to center my container that contains Material, TextButton, and IconButton widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my buttons look like this:

[image]

Currently, it's looking like this (I'm just focusing on implementing one icon and text button which are side by side correctly and then I can just copy and paste for the others):

[image]

I'm trying to center-align the profile and icon buttons, I used TextButton and IconButton to do these, but I haven't been able to. I've also tried wrapping them in a Center widget but that didn't work. I'm assuming I organized my code and widgets wrong, here's my code:

```
Container( // container holding the main setting buttons
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 0, left: 30, right: 30),
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, top: 7, right: 10, bottom: 8),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton( // TODO: CHANGE ICON TO EXACT FROM FIGMA
                              iconSize: 20,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                              onPressed: () {
                                // TODO: NO FUNCTIONALITY FOR BUTTON
                              },
                            ),
                            
                            TextButton(
                              
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                foregroundColor: Colors.black, // color of text
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                
                              },
                              child: const Text("Privacy"), // TODO: CHANGE FONT
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text("Terms of Service")),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text("Community Rules")),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text("Report a problem")),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text("Become a Pioneer")),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text("Log out")),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text("Manage account"))
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace the ElevatedButtons by a ListTile

***Example:*** remove the

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text("Terms of Service")),
```

***then add***

```
ListTile(onTap:(){},title:Text("Terms of Service"),leading: Icon(Icons.add))
ListTile(onTap:(){},title:Text("Community Rules" ),leading: Icon(Icons.add))
```

and if you wrap the **ListTiles** on a **SizedBox** you can set the  width as you wish.

---

but if you just want to center those widgets:

then the  Column should have a

> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center

and the row you put the first button should have :

> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center

Comment: How would I get rid of the padding the SizedBox widget brings?

Comment: ListTile has a default Padding. You can just remove it with 'contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,' inside your ListTile